# What happened to the off-topic close reasons on Meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions, off-topic

Edit: My apologies, my observation is actually totally invalid. Not sure why I thought it was true, but eh. Sorry for bothering.

On Meta, the off-topic close reasons seem to have vanished. Take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199668/big-banner-shown-to-answer-writer-if-question-got-a-vote-to-close); the close reason reads:

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

However, you can't actually select this as a close reason. This is the main header for the off topic close reasons. **What doesn't show is the real close reason:**

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

Because the real close reason doesn't show, and because "off topic" is a complete misnomer, the wrong close reason is stated to apply to the question. Could these please be changed back to the real close reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the question gets closed using a **custom off-topic** reason, it always displays the standard "this is off-topic" message in the close notice. The real reason for closure on that question is in the [automatically created comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199668/big-banner-shown-to-answer-writer-if-question-got-a-vote-to-close#comment634607_199668):

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rant that has nothing to do with the title feature request.

Not specific to Meta. This occurs on all sites on any question which is closed for a custom reason.

Comment: Hey, my best ever custom off-topic reason is now immortalized in a post

Comment: I'm not sure this applies. I'm not talking about the _custom written_ close reasons, I'm talking about _site specific_ close reasons. The ones that say "problem can no longer be reproduced" or some such. This was probably my error in terminology usage, but even so, the reason doesn't show up.

Comment: @Emrakul They still exist. But *no one* voted to close that question using any of those site-specific reasons. The first person entered a custom reason in the "other" box, and the four following users selected that same reason. Why would it show one of the site-specific reasons when no one selected one?

Comment: Agh, you're right, this isn't a bug at all. The reasons are showing up. That's... weird. Sorry to bother; mine wasn't actually a valid observation to begin with.