# Display the custom close reason when closed as such

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, custom-close-reasons

### Background

As per [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199896/220332) where a custom close reason is used the actual close reason is shown as:

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the
> software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope
> defined in the help centre.

I had previously believed this was a bug<sup>1</sup> but I would now like to feature request that the behaviour be changed:

### Feature request

Where a custom closure reason is used display that rather than just the generic message. So it would look like:

[image]

### Reasoning

Custom close reasons are likely to be the most specific and helpful close reasons a question is likely to get. As such it seems a shame to relegate them to the comments. Worse still comments, as second class citizens, can be deleted at any time for any reason. Potentially leaving no indication why a question was closed.

A custom close reason is more than any old comment, it is the opinion of (for it to be displayed) at least 3 senior members of the community, as such it should be the first thing the question OP addresses.

### Possible concerns

I can imagine a concern with this being that *anything* could go into the reason and recieve seemingly official sanction. However, I feel this is mitigated for three reasons:

1. Other 3k+ users must agree with the custom close reason for it to be displayed
2. The reason is placed under "The users who voted to close gave this specific reason" making it clear that this is the opinion of those users not of stack exchange itself
3. We have flags for any serious problems

<sup>1</sup> you may remember some testing I did regarding that, that thread is now deleted since it added nothing as I was testing for [status-bydesign] behaviour

Comment: AFAICR we already do this unless two different close reasons were proffered by the close voters.

Comment: @Grinch On [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215044/remove-the-age-tag?noredirect=1) I personally put in the 4th vote on the custom reason to close the question (5th vote was not custom). Must the custom choice be unanimous to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think even unanimous custom closes don't show like this. In [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220301/if-you-wanted-to-become-an-expert-lever-coder-in-the-fastest-possible-way-how-w) a mod unanimous closed using a custom reason but it still showed up as generic