# Remove the [age] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are 145 questions tagged with [age](/questions/tagged/age).

They seem to relate to a bunch of different things - none of which particularly helpful in classifying the question. Needless to say it has no wiki.

I'm going to start editing it out of existing questions.

This is a call for help, if anyone wants to help me edit the tag out of questions I'd love that.

Comment: Good work everyone! This was really efficient and really quick!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is done!

Comment: The age of [age] has now ended...

Comment: Why are we closing a burninate request as off topic? It's already marked [[tag:status-completed]].