# Are burninate requests off-topic on meta now?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, meta, off-topic, burninate-request

I've seen that the question [Remove the [age] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215044/remove-the-age-tag) was put on hold.

In the past I wrote several of such questions here on meta, and there are even tags for it: [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) and [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) with 1,170 questions here on meta.so.

I also believe that moderation things like "what tags should exist" belongs here on meta.

So why the hell was this question put on hold?

**Edit**: by the way, burninate [age](/questions/tagged/age) (yes, meta-[age](/questions/tagged/age))?

Comment: Because...it was done so fast?  Why would burnination be off-topic?  There's dozens of those questions/discussions active now!

Comment: Meh, we have a close reason for that: "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question. "

Comment: It's not on hold anymore...

Comment: Also, it's marked "status-completed" (i.e. [age] is already burninated), so no need to add a plug there.

Comment: I just want to nip it in the bud.

Answer (score 9):

The request was closed because it was made obsolete soon after.

You just can't close something as obsolete (and no longer needing any attention) without also saying it's off topic. Even if it was on topic.

The question then becomes [what use is a retag/merge/burninate request that was not debated and does not follow through to live tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60227/please-stop-deleting-retag-requests) as initially outlined, but has been completed.

And some like to close things before they delete them. Full paperwork and all that.

Comment: One problem with these deletions is that they remove an action from the *public* record.  Normal users are no longer able to find previous actions should they become relevant again.  It's a minor thing, really...

Comment: In cases where it looks contentious, then they're not as likely going to be closed/deleted. For typos, plurals and hyphen cases, they're less likely to crop up again.

Comment: [Oh, hello, Humpty Dumpty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Not only are burninate requests still on-topic, you found an exceptionally successful one.

Note that [meta-age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) is... actually kinda useful.

Comment: The request at the end is not for the so-tag. It is for a similar useful tag here on meta.SO.

Comment: Well, now I look foolish! I kinda think [meta-tag:age] is useful, given the unfortunate relevance of age to certain policies.

Comment: I "discovered" this tag when I looked at the revision history of the linked question. That irony.