# Misleading closed reason

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, custom-close-reasons

Just not an everyday situation I have experienced today;

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403467/the-program-is-very-slow-why-in-c-sharp) earlier today with 3 custom close votes. It pretty much said something "this question is off-topic as it should be on codereview". I agreed it should (4th vote).

So my guess is: it received 5 custom close votes which closed the question as off-topic but the current reason provided is actually a bit misleading since we can't close a question as it belongs to another stack exchange site » [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) *in this case, which was the intention.*

[image]

So now, the reason just says the question is off-topic, which (*debatable*, but) would make it on-topic only if 5 people didn't know codereview existed...

It doesn't tell you nor the OP that the 5 voters agreed to a common reason that the question belongs somewhere else in the Stack Exchange network.

While this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) it is a bit misleading as the actual reason the qestion was closed is not listed anywhere.

Should this be amended?

Comment: Strongly related;  [Display the custom close reason when closed as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211893/display-the-custom-close-reason-when-closed-as-such)

Comment: You should not be closing a question as offtopic if the question is on topic, but there is another site that you feel it is also on topic for.  You should only close the question if it is not on topic on the current site.  Note however that most code review type questions meet some condition for closure on SO (they're usually too broad, too localized, it's unclear what they're asking, etc.).

Comment: related: [Could the close vote banner please be made less… well, wrong?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172654/could-the-close-vote-banner-please-be-made-less-well-wrong)