# Are custom-close-reason comments auto-upvoted when you VTC with that reason?

Tags: support, comments, vote-to-close, comment-voting, custom-close-reasons

I just voted to close something with someone else's custom reason. Their comment with that custom reason was upvoted, apparently by me, right as the VTC "took", despite the fact that *I didn't issue a command to upvote it.* Furthermore, I am now unable to unupvote it. (The question was [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228675/223030) pre-deletion.)

What's going on? And if this is an official automated thing, why isn't it a thing for duplicates yet?!

Comment: I believe so, which is good because [voting to close with a custom reason has no other effect,  grumble grumble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211893/display-the-custom-close-reason-when-closed-as-such)

Comment: `why isn't it a thing for duplicates yet` - I might be remembering incorrectly, but I seem to recall it did used to auto-upvote duplicates, but the feature was broken at some point and never fixed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 true, about the same time it stopped showing the dupe auto comment, until reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, when you select a custom reason when voting to close you automatically upvote it.  This was simply how that feature was designed when it was implemented.

Comment: Hmm... I guess that was to emphasize the close explanation, perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewBarber  Yeah, when readers come across the question after it's been closed the close reason needs to stand out, since the custom text isn't stuck in the close box.  It would be bad for it to be hidden in a longer comment thread.